# Importing ApolloProvider as a component

Tags: reactjs, apollo, graphql-js, react-apollo

I would like to use [react-apollo](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo) in a project.

Following the setup steps in [the usage section](https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo#usage), I can get the `<ApolloProvider>` working if it's the root of my React Component tree:

```
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <MyRootComponent />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

However, I would like to import the `<ApolloProvider>` as a component within my tree, not at the root.

When I try doing this, I get this err:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. Check the render method of `MyGraphQl`.
```

Is there a way to import this as a normal component?

Comment: Why would you want to have it somewhere else than your root level? Is there a part of your application which shouldn't know about Apollo? Otherwise it's a common pattern to use a Provider at the root (see [Provider Pattern](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-provider-pattern-context/)).

Comment: Please post your code that produces the error. It will be easier to understand the problem with it.